# conditional formatting fails after file reopen

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Following works as intended but once I close & reopen the excel file it fails & only executes once if I change something in the same column, add/delete a tab or on file load. Hitting F9 does nothing. If I manually go into the existing conditional formatting & reapply it properly works again, despite changing nothing, but close & reopen file & same problem.

```
    rngNew = "D1" & ":" & Cells(lRowEnd, 4).Address
    Set rngShopTime = Range(rngNew)

    Dim txtShopFree As String
    txtShopFree = "=""ShopFree"""
    Dim rngShop As String
    rngShop = "C1" & ":" & Cells(lRowEnd, 3).Address(False, True)
    With rngShopTime
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & rngShop & txtShopFree
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
        With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
            .SetFirstPriority
            With .Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End With
    End With
```

I have isolated to this code & it still happens.
How would I troubleshoot or rework this, as I'm not getting any errors at all.

Excel version 2013 & 2010.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably need to delete any existing format conditions before you add the new one.

Comment: Why would you keep running the Conditional Format  code? Set the CF for columns c & d and be done with it.

Comment: @Davesexcel because this relies on another column of that contains its own data validation & doing that too on the whole column would probably bog the spreadsheet down even more & add to the filesize, which I'm trying to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix.

Changed

```
rngShop = "C1" & ":" & Cells(lRowEnd, 3).Address(False, True)
```

To

```
rngShop = "C1" & txtShopFree
```

And

```
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & rngShop & txtShopFree
```

To

```
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & rngShop
```

Answer (score 0):

I have office 2003 Professional, but this should still apply as it is probably event and location driven.

I am guessing that you are not running the code on the Workbook_Open event of the ThisWorkbook Object and instead somewhere in a sheet.

Therefore, you should put your code into the Workbook_Open event and try that.

```
    'This is code on the ThisWorkbook Object
    '-------------------------------------------
    Option Explicit

    Private Sub Workbook_Open()

        Sheet1.Columns("D:D").Select
        Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
            Formula1:="0"
        Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
            Formula1:="1"
        Selection.FormatConditions(2).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
    End Sub
```

Comment: Issue is that the code is just a sample that highlights the problem & once called is placed in several places not just one column. Edit: it's called dynamically & loaded in these places which can expand as the data grows.

Comment: If it is called dynamically then, you need to store where the conditions happen dynamically and then read the information from that location (whether that location is in another sheet or on a text file stored on the computer.)
  Ex:  FormatCols = "Sheet1, D : Sheet1,  F : Sheet2, C : Sheet3, A : etc..."